# Different error message on jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin.

I have a required url input, and when it is empty it return error "This field is required.".

What I want is when the value of this input will be 'home', the error to be changed to "There is already a homepage". But only when 'home' is typed in the input field.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#edit_pages_form").validate({
    errorClass: "has-error",
    validClass: "has-success",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest("div")
            .addClass(errorClass)
            .removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest("div")
            .removeClass(errorClass)
            .addClass(validClass);
    }
});
```

You may notice that I highlight the input field and when empty I add has-error class, when not empty I add has-success class.

What I want is when 'home' is entered as value, the class has-error to be added.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom validation methods:

```html
<form class="cmxform" id="edit_pages_form" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("isHome", function(value, element) {
    if (value.length == 4) {
      return (value != "home");
    }
    return true;
  }, "There is already a homepage");

  $("#edit_pages_form").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        isHome: true
      }
    },
    errorClass: "has-error",
    validClass: "has-success",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).closest("div")
        .addClass(errorClass)
        .removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).closest("div")
        .removeClass(errorClass)
        .addClass(validClass);
    }
  });


});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qtgahxss/1/

Comment: When I type home nothing happens

Comment: I did, maybe there is any conflict in my code I don't what can be the problem, all day I am looking for an answer

Comment: One more point, in the JS above you will need to rename 'name' to match the name of your input field, if you have not done so already.

Comment: I didn't change the name, I  thought that it could be the mistake, but I changed and tried again and nothing happened...

Comment: Are you able to provide your complete code / HTML + JavaScript?

Comment: hmmm I can't before I ask.. so thanks again, I hope I will provide html js files after asking. Thanks brother for the help really appreciate, I will write again

Comment: Hello my friend, I tried again the code today and it perfectly works!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if statement to check if the value is home?

```
$("#edit_pages_form").validate({
errorClass: "has-error",
validClass: "has-success",
has-error: "has-error",
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
if($('#url-texbox-id').val() == "home"){
 $(element).closest("div")
        .addClass(has-error);
        .removeClass(validClass);
}
else{
    $(element).closest("div")
        .addClass(errorClass)
        .removeClass(validClass);
        }
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest("div")
        .removeClass(errorClass)
        .addClass(validClass);
}
});
```

Comment: In what way? did you add "url-texbox-id" as an id to the textbox?